# Making an iteration inside a Join function

Tags: pandas

I have the next doubt.
How does that "for iteration" inside the join works?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': ['2014', '2015'],
    'Col2': ['40000', '50000']})
df['cost'] = df[['Col1', 'Col2']].apply(
    lambda x: '|'.join([str(i) for i in x]), axis=1)+'|'
```

Comment: google "python list comprehensions", here is one explanation https://stackoverflow.com/q/47789/6692898

Answer (score 0):

It basically iterates `x` and cast each element of `x` into a string.
The result is a list with string representations of the elements of `x`.

Given e.g. a string "test", the result would be `['t', 'e', 's', 't']` and after the join operation you would end up with `'t|e|s|t'`

In your case, you would end up with `2014|40000|` and `2015|50000|`

Note that the last `|` is due to the `+'|'`